# How to give total in float using javascript

Tags: javascript

How to give total in float using javascript. Please help me friends.

```
<script language="javascript">
            function addNumbers()
            {
                    var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value1").value);
                    var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value2").value);
                    var ansD = document.getElementById("answer");

                    ansD.value = val1 * val2;
            }
    </script>
```

Comment: instead of `parseInt` use `parseFloat`

Comment: If there is a big calculation then you should try this: https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js

Comment: I think your `addNumbers` function should be `multiplyNumbers`?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var val1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("value1").value);
var val2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("value2").value);
```

Instead Of:

```
var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value1").value);
var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value2").value);
```

Comment: Thank you friends. Now show but after (.), it show one digit only.How to show 2 digit friends

Comment: use (Math.round((ansD.value)* 100) / 100)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
                var val1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("value1").value);
                var val2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("value2").value);
                var ansD = document.getElementById("answer");

                ansD.value = val1 * val2;
```

Or Just remove the parseInt();

```
                var val1 = document.getElementById("value1").value;
                var val2 = document.getElementById("value2").value;
                var ansD = document.getElementById("answer");

                ansD.value = val1 * val2;
```

also if you want to change floating point number precision, use following line

```
ansD.value = parseFloat(val1 * val2).toPrecision(3); // gives two floating points
```